# How to make sure each character of a command argument is a decimal digit?

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, digits, atoi

We have to make a code to encrypt Caesar's cipher. One of the steps is: instead of printing out the command-line argument provided, your program instead checks to make sure that each character of that command line argument is a decimal digit (i.e., `0`, `1`, `2`, etc.) and, if any of them are not, terminates after printing the message Usage: ./caesar key. But if the argument consists solely of digit characters, you should convert that string (recall that `argv` is an array of strings, even if those strings happen to look like numbers) to an actual integer, and print out the integer, as via `%i` with `printf`.
The code below is what I have, but it returns both Success & Error. How can I fix this so that the program checks that each character of the command line argument is a digit? 
[Code I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPxta.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please take a minute to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi. Your question's title says "C++". Your tags say "C". These are different languages. Please choose one.

Comment: Please copy your code into your question, using the Markdown syntax for code samples (A line with three ``` before and after the code.) Images are (1) hard to read on mobile devices (and by people who use screen readers, etc.), and (2) even harder to copy into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`isdigit` apply on an `int` containing the code of a character but doing `isdigit(atoi(argv[1]))` you try first to convert the string to an integer so this is wrong. If you use `isdigit` this is iterating on all the string.

`atoi` silently returns 0 when the argument is not a valid integer, do not use it.

This is not because the string contains only digits that you can get the corresponding `int` because the number can be too large for an `int`. If you accept negative number the first character can be `-` which is not a digit. One way to both convert and check all the string represents a valid integer is to use `strtol` returning a `long`.

Out of that when `argc` is not 2 you must terminate the execution rather than continue as you do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to check that all characters in a string are in a given set:

```
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc > 1) {
        if (strspn(argv[1], "0123456789") == strlen(argv[1]))
            printf("OK\n");
        else
            printf("Invalid characters\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You might want to check that the command line argument has at least 1 character.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this thing in an efficient way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool isNumber(char number[])
{
    int i = 0;

    if (strlen(number) == 0) // checks for empty string
        return false;

    if (strlen(number) == 1 && number[0] == '-') // checks for invalid str with negation sign
        return false;

    if (number[0] == '-') // verifies negation sign
        i = 1;

    for (; number[i] != 0; i++)
        if (!isdigit(number[i]))
            return false; // if not a number

    return true; // if number
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (isNumber(argv[1]))
        printf("%d\n", atoi(argv[1])); // ... statements
    else
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");

    return 0;
}
```

You can safely use `atoi()` after validating the arguments are correctly given. Consider:

```
if (isNumber(argv[1]))
    printf("Go on\n");
else
    printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
```

### Sample Output

```
$ ./caesar
Usage: ./caesar key
$ ./caesar s
Usage: ./caesar key
$ ./caesar 123 // --- right one
123
$ ./caesar s 3 f
Usage: ./caesar key
```

Comment: `You can safely use atoi() after validating the arguments are correctly given` : no, you missed the possible overflow

Comment: @bruno If the argument is given an overflowed integer, it'll obviously throw incorrect output.

Comment: no more nor less than without checking the string represent an integer ^^

Comment: note also you consider an empty string or the string containing only `-` to be the valid presentation of an integer

Comment: you missed the case of an empty string. And to call `strlen` then to iterate on the string means the string is read two times, and to convert a third read will be done, remember you said *efficient way* ^^

Comment: @bruno now the code seems to be working fine in *efficient way*.

Comment: efficient while you added an other calls to `strlen` to read the string up to 4 times ?